# Showing the desktop version of all Stack exchange sites by default on tablets

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I think that the desktop versions of the site's are a much better fit to tablet screens then the mobile versions of the sites. This already happens on SO for whatever reason, as I get the desktop version of the site (when I am using my tablet), but on meta I am given the mobile version of the site which, is a shame because the full desktop version of the site is great.

Is there a reason that this has not been done? Or are tablet SE users such a minority that they haven't been considered before?

Comment: What version you use is stored in a cookie; you probably switched SO to the desktop version already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Pieters I may have, but I can't figure out how I could have done that(nor can I remember doing it), so I assumed it was the website

Comment: There is a link in the footer (`full site` for mobile sites, `mobile` for full sites) to toggle between the interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that before(though I guess I must have clicked it)

Answer (score 3):

It is becoming increasingly difficult to just detect 'tablet' these days. At one end of the spectrum there are tablets running mobile (i.e. cellphone) OS's - such as early or cheap 2.0 Android ones, and at the other end of the scale there are tablets running Windows 8. If you start detecting all the various OS's and device types you end up having to maintain a huge list of devices and user agents to check against, and you'll never catch all of them. Not to mention that no two devices are exactly the same anyway (different screen resolutions, different browsers etc).

The only real option is to redo the whole site using media queries to create a Responsive website that displays content based on the screen size of the devices and browers that are viewing it instead of having distinct mobile / desktop versions.

(I would be all for a responsive version of StackExchange, but that's a much bigger job than tweaking the desktop and mobile versions here and there).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info